# Is there a templated type generalizing int4, uint4, float4 etc.?

Tags: c++, templates, cuda, vectorization

I'm writing a CUDA kernel which should operate on vectors of various types. No problem - use `template<typename T>`, right? But what if I want to work on vectors of *vectorized* scalar types?

For the sake of discussion suppose I want to be able to handle all of `int4`, `uint4`, `float4` etc. Is there some kind of `Quad<T>` type I can use? As part of CUDA or a C++ standard library type? A 'Tuple` would also do.

**Notes:**

- While this question is CUDA-related, it is not CUDA-specific.
- I would like a solution which does not require me to 'implement' the template (e.g. using int4, uint4 or other structs of my own definition.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use type traits. For example

```
#include <cuda.h>

template<typename T> struct vectorized_type;

template<> struct vectorized_type<int>   { typedef int4 vect_type; };

int main () {

    vectorized_type<int>::vect_type test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems this requires me bot to typedef T4 and to manually instatiate vectorized_type<T> for every single T I want to use.

Comment: It will be not much effort. It will require as many program lines as the number of involved types is. If you are interested in `int4`, `uint4` and `float4`, this will require three instances, which is much less than redefining, in a templated manner, such types.

Comment: I'm interested in writing something generic, with all sorts of types. And - what can I see, this is just not satisfactory to me :-(

Comment: This is not clear from your post. The alternative that I see is to redefine in a templated manner the above CUDA types, but you should be careful because they usually require additional alignment properties.

Comment: Clarified the question to indicate I don't want to have to instantiate anything myself. As for alignment... that might be tricky. I don't suppose it can be handled in a templated manner? If not, I guess I'll need some alignment-checking assertions for templated code using the vectorized type to work.